# How to fix that style tag is not accessed in vue native?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-native

I am trying to display a blue text in vue native, however, it only displays the text without the color. I am using a style tag which has the style info.

I tried using an inline styling and it worked, therefore, I think the problem lays with accessing the style tag.

```
<template>
  <view class="container">
    <text class="text-color-primary">My Vue Native App</text>
    </view>
</template>

<style>
 .container {
  background-color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}
.text-color-primary {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Here is a link to what I am getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/py9XL.png

The expected outcome should be the same text, however, the color is blue and must be in the middle of the screen.

Comment: can you share running code snippet ?

Comment: use http://stackblitz.com/

Comment: You mean the App.vue? That's what I have already in the code snippet I shared. @C2486

Comment: @Yoarthur, are you suggesting the the issue is with the IDE?

Comment: use http://stackblitz.com/ to deploy your code

Comment: That doesn't help because the App.vue is a vue component. stackblitz.com doesn't render vue @Yoathur

Comment: use then http://jsfiddle.net/. ;)

Comment: There is no problem with the code. The issue is still there